# Poor TTY resolution with nVidia driver

Tags: terminal, grub2, nvidia, tty

The resolution of the TTY1-6 is poor ~ 640×480

Ubuntu 11.10 | Grub2 | nVidia | NVIDIA GT215 Board

I went through the process on this [site](http://www.conanblog.me/it/how-to-get-the-high-resolution-for-tty-back-after-nvidia-driver-update-in-ubuntu/) and after the edit the GRUB menu appears in the correct (more refined resolution). But after it boots into GNOME (via gdm3) and I attempt to view terminal 1-6 the screen is barely or completely unreadable.

I am able to revert my changes but I am looking to restore the fine resolution the terminal screens are capable of.

To determine the screen resolutions avail. to me, I used:

```
hwinfo --framebuffer | grep "Mode"
Mode 0x0369: 1680x1050 (+6720), 24 bits
```

These are the steps I went through. edit 1) grub config 2) initramfs modules, then 3) update

```
sudo vi  /etc/default/grub
```

Find the fol­low­ing three lines.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet  splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
...
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640×480
```

Change them to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1680x1050-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="vga=0x0369"
...
GRUB_GFXMODE=1680x1050
```

Then:

```
sudo vi  /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
```

Adding/editing line:

```
uvesafb mode_option=1680x1050-24 mtrr=3 scroll=ywrap
```

Cre­ate a new file:

```
echo FRAMEBUFFER=y |  sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
```

Finally update the configuration files:

```
sudo update-grub2
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Again, the GRUB menu in the beginning of the boot-up process shows the more refined resolution (including small font size), but small refined focused resolution disappears for terminals after boot up.

Comment: In earlier versions (Maverick), I forced the TTY resolution with this in `/etc/default/grub`: `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1680x1050`. Also, if you are using `uvesafb` have you installed `v86d`?

Comment: v86d installed and the latest version (according to apt-get), the interesting thing is that the grub resolution appears as 1680x1050 but as soon as the boot up process begins the resolution returns to (a lousy) 640×480.

Comment: This was my `/etc/default/grub` from Maverick: http://codepad.org/vkufRCcb

Comment: Are you also using the edits in uvesafb?

Comment: I'm no longer running Ubuntu: and at the time I didn't use `uvesafb` - the above config was all I needed to set the correct console resolution.

Comment: If you're using the proprietary nVidia driver, it can't do full framebuffer, etc. I had massive problems with that, and I still kinda struggle with it. If you ask for things I've asked in the past, you'll find my questions to the same topics.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following after your `GRUB_GFXMODE` line in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. Installed the `nvidia` graphics drivers on Debian and suddenly the TTY resolution went awry. I was not particularly worried about the resolution of GRUB itself though, only the console I would get from it.

With such simplifications of the problem the following portion from the OP worked perfectly for me:

> `sudo vi  /etc/initramfs-tools/modules`
>
> Adding/editing line:
>
> `uvesafb mode_option=1680x1050-24 mtrr=3 scroll=ywrap`
>
> Finally update the configuration files:
>
> `sudo update-initramfs -u`

I did also try the suggestion to simply add the `vga=0x0369` parameter to the kernel command line. This did not work for me with the `3.2.0` kernel though

Answer (score 0):

The `nvidia` driver doesn't support high resolution for tty, but you can use `nouveau` instead of `nvidia`

Comment: Apparently it does for @DanCat...

Comment: I use grub, grub2 supports buffers upper than 16M ? (0x31B)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to have a high resolution in the GRUB bootup screen? If not, simply add `vga=0xXXXX` to the kernel commandline. This works perfectly for me (running an nVidia-ION notebook with the closed-source nVidia driver).